# SQL without table creation

Tags: sql

Is there any possibility to use subqueries for string changes?

I can't create any new tables on database, just read the result.

My problem is like this: There is a table T1 with two columns, C1 and C2 (and others, but these one together are a key). I must get a list of all entries C1, C2, such that the pair C1, C2'' is not an entry in T1, where

```
C2'' = SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(C2, '\\', 1) AND CHARINDEX('\\',C2) > 0;
```

meaning, if C2 includes a backslash, the entry with shorter name "until backslash" isn't in the table (and if C2 does not includes a backslash, I do not get it anyway).

Thank you very much in advance,
khitron23

Sorry. Sure.

T1:

```
C1 |C2
abc|def
jkhk|abcde\\grt
lkjk|hkjhk\\kjg
khkh|khkhk\\ghh
jkhk|abcde
lkjl|hkjhk
```

The result:

```
C1|C2''
lkjk|hkjhk\\kjg
khkh|khkhk\\ghh
```

Just those, because there are no

```
lkjk|hkjhk
khkh|khkhk
```

in initial table.

The server is http://quarry.wmflabs.org. C1 | C2'' means a column C1 and a column C2'', it's just a name.
What I really want is like this (for anyone who knows wiki syntax):
There is a table of Wikipedia pages with two key columns - namespace+title.
I want to recognize all sub pages (e.g. Portal:Biology\answers\5) that do not have top pages (as Portal:Biology). Usually this is a problem of "forgot do delete subpage when top page was deleted".
The server can read Wikipedia tables but can't change or create new ones.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: What you're asking for sounds doable, I just can't figure out what you're asking for :)

Comment: I'm having a lot of following this question... can you reword it and provide current outcome, expected outcome, sample data, etc?

Comment: @Khitron23 . . . Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also tag which DBMS you are using... sql server, mysql, etc.

Comment: If you are using SQL server, you might be allowed to create temporary tables even with a read-only user. Just add a `#` before the table name (`##` if you want a temp-table that is global to the database server.)

Comment: What does this mean? `C1|C2''` - why the two single quotes following `C2`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't need to escape '\' char (depends on SQL engine), next idea would work (a1 and a2 are just aliases to not confuse columns):

```
select * 
from t1 as a1
where a1.c2 like '%\%'
and not exists (
    select * 
    from t1 as a2 
    where a1.c1 = a2.c1 
        and a1.c2 like a2.c2 + '\%'
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Arvo, but it's a weird server: it does not recognize "+". Can we do this by select as I wrote above?

Comment: I don't know - my experience is limited to servers, allowing to use '+' operator :( Do you have any other operator instead? Without string conacatenation my idea is not that usable.

Comment: C2'' = SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(C2, '\\', 1) AND CHARINDEX('\\',C2) > 0; is not good?